# I've inserted AddThis Social Button code into Magento. Why is the product url now garbled?

Tags: magento, url, hyperlink, product

The url of my product pages is now garbled. A sample link：

`http://www.chouchoudress.com/product/fabulous-asymmetrical-ruffles-prom-graduation-dress-with-one-crystal-straps.html#.UR-CjfKptdt`

The garbled addition to the link is `#.UR-CjfKptdt` specifically some sort of code preceeded by `#.`.

Can anyone tell me why?

Comment: ...perhaps the referring context will be more helpful?

Comment: Another Magento website owner who has tripped and fallen flat over using AddThis for putting social disease buttons on their website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’ve started using AddThis for your social networking and weren’t warned of the implications of using their **social link tracking** feature.

AddThis adds hash snot (`#.` and an identifier) to the end of your URL to enable tracking links pasted from your website into blog articles, comments, etc. which then breaks functions in Magento.

Remove the hash snot with a simple change to the inserted AddThis javascript snippet.

Find the line in the AddThis javascript snippet with `data_track_addressbar` and remove it. This shuts off the hash string for tracking pasted links.

Comment: Glad to be of help, the `#.` junk had a weird effect on my dev server till I tracked it down. The bosses wanted the buttons, fortunately I didn't go live with the template with the code AddThis spit at me or we'd have had cussing customers... Not a good thing.